# Microsoft Access Form - Auto Populate Form Field From Another Form

Tags: microsoft-access

I have been searching for the answer to this but can not find anything.

I have one main Access form and several Sub Forms in different tabs on the main form. There is a single field on each Sub Form that needs to be populated from the main form. I have tried to set the control source to the field that contains the data I need to be auto populated on each Sub Form but the fields are blank when I change tabs to show each Sub Form.

Do I have to use Visual Basic to actually make this happen or am I not doing it right by setting the control source?

Comment: Are those fields in the sub form being saved as records in a table? What are you typing into the control source? You don't have to, but VBA can be used to populate the fields.

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes the fields in the sub form are being saved as records in a table, although they don't really have to be. It is more of a method for keeping track of the current record you are working on. I have tried this in the control source `Forms![Demographics Form]![ID Field] ` and `[Demographics]![ID Field] `

Comment: Try `=[ID Field]` in the Control Source field to see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties of a form control you can enter the value of another field by using `=[controlname]` in the Control Source. In your case it is `=[ID Field]` in the Control Source of each of the fields you want to reflect the `ID Field` value.

Here is a gif of how I did it in a simple form.

[image]
[large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fyRz.gif)